# Using XOR operator to determine if there are duplicates in a list of integers

Tags: python, list, xor

I have a list of numbers:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,19,22,25,17,6,73,72,71,77,899,887,44,124, ...]
#this is an abbreviated version of the list
```

I need to determine if there are duplicates in the list or not using the XOR ("^") operator.

Can anyone give me any tips?  I'm a newbie and have never encountered this problem or used the XOR operator before.

I've tried several approaches (which have amounted to blind stabs in the dark).  The last one was this:

```
MyDuplicatesList = [1,5,12,156,166,2656,6,4,5,9] #changed the list to make it easer
for x in MyDuplicatesList:
    if x^x:
    print("True")
```

I realize I'm probably violating a protocol by asking such an open-ended question, but I'm completely stumped.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just to give you a start: If you have a number x, then x ^ x is 0, and x ^ 0 is x. That means that x^x ^x is x. Another XOR question I've found involves using these properties to find a single element that appears an odd number of times when the others appear an even number of times. But that means running an XOR over the list won't tell you whether you have a duplicate or not if there are multiple duplicates.

Comment: Just to be clear: [1,2,3] should report no duplicates, as should [1,2,4,7], while [1,2,1] should report yes, as should [1,2,1,2].

Comment: @synchronizer I just edited my original question to show the latest code I tried.  Don't laugh--as I said, I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: FWIW, this would be a lot easier if you're allowed to sort the list.

Answer (score 4):

Why XOR?

```
# true if there are duplicates
print len(set(a)) != len(a)
```

Ok, THIS is pythonic. It finds all the duplicates and makes a list of them.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,19,22,25,17,6,73,72,71,77,899,887,44,124,1]
b = [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(i+1,len(a)) if i ^ j > 0 if a[i] ^ a[j] < 1]

print b
```

Simplified version of Dalen's idea:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,19,22,25,17,6,73,72,71,77,899,887,44,124,1]

def simplifyDalen(source):
    dup = 0

    for x in source:
        for y in source:
            dup += x ^ y == 0

    return dup ^ len(source) > 0

result = simplifyDalen(a)

if result:
    print "There are duplicates!"
else:
    print "There are no duplicates!"
```

So far my bit index idea is the fastest (because it's one pass algorithm, I guess, not many to many)

Comment: That is what the assignment calls for.  I've already done it using the method you suggested.

Comment: Oh, sorry then : )

Comment: `len(x) - len(set(x)) ^ 0 > 0` technically uses XOR

Comment: @sdolan  Thank you.  That worked.  I wish I understood why.  :-(

Comment: @AndrewSmith well, learn why. You're prof will probably notice, so be prepared to defend it.

Comment: @sdolan Yesh dude, that sound a bit harsh. Maybe give him a pointer in the right direction?

Comment: @AndrewSmith and it works because len(x) - len(set(x)) returns 0 if theyre the same (sets removes all of the duplicates as part of the type). Then 0^0 == 0 if it's the same and x^0 will be greater than 0 if not.

Comment: Oh, BTW: print len(a) ^ len(set(a)) > 0

Comment: @leaf: Wasn't meant to be, just saying that he shouldn't take the answer at face value. It's an obscure way of doing it, so it may raise questions.

Comment: Aye aye. I've added an actual XOR solution below.

Comment: @Andrew Smith : Open up an interpreter and start paying around with 1 and 0 while looking at the various bitwise operator. Pull out a scrap of paper too until it clicks. This is probably just one of many questions around this that will come up, better to get into it and sort it out now. It'll save you headaches in the future.

Comment: @AndrewSmithL I wrote a test hardness to test out your various algorithms: https://repl.it/FJNa/0

Comment: You should bail out of the loops as soon as you find a dupe.

Comment: +1, just please only one L in my name. And, I thought of list comprehension, but I would use sum() and an iterator, not list (to only find if there are or no duplicates. But then do not complain to me that the code is complicated. :D See, I don't think this is Pythonic at all. It too much smells on functional programming.

Answer (score 3):

When you xor two same numbers, you get 0. As you should know.

```
from operator import xor

def check (lst):
    dup = 0
    for x in lst:
        for y in lst:
            dup += xor(x, y)!=0
    l = len(lst)
    return dup!=(l**2 -l)

c = check([0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,5])

if c:
    print "There are duplicates!"
else:
    print "There are no duplicates!"
```

BTW, this is extremely stupid way to do it. XORing is fast, but O(n**2) (always through whole set) is unnecessary loss.
For one thing, the iteration should be stopped when first duplicate is encountered.
For another, this really should be done using set() or dict().
But you can get the idea.

Also, using xor() function instead of bitwise operator '^' slows the thing down a bit. I did it for clarity as I complicated the rest of the code. And so that people know that it exists as an alternative.

Here is an example on how to do it better.
It's a slight modification of code suggested by Organis in comments.

```
def check (lst):
    l = len(lst)
    # I skip comparing first with first and last with last
    # to prevent 4 unnecessary iterations. It's not much, but it makes sense.
    for x in xrange(1, l):
        for y in xrange(l-1):
            # Skip elements on same position as they will always xor to 0  :D
            if x!=y: # Can be (if you insist): if x^y != 0:...
                if (lst[x] ^ lst[y])==0:
                    return 1 # Duplicate found
    return 0 # No duplicates

c = check([0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,5])

if c:
    print "There are duplicates!"
else:
    print "There are no duplicates!"
```

To repeat, XOR is not to be used for comparison, at least not in high-level programming languages. It's possible you would need similar thing in assembly for some reason, but eq works nicely there as anywhere. If we simply used == here instead, we would be able to check for duplicates in lists containing anything, not just integers.

XOR is fancy for other uses, as for ordinary bitwising (masking, unmasking, changing bits...), so in encryption systems and similar stuff.

Comment: No, it should be faster actually, but this is a bit obviouser. Especially for those not familiar with xor operator.

Comment: xor(0, 1) is 1, not 0. If xor is 0, then it is a duplicate. Did I do something wrong with loops. I am sleepy.

Comment: You compare many to many skipping the wrong element in the inner loop.

Comment: Yes-yes, I just saw. Thank you!

Comment: Something like for i in range(len(lst)): for j in range(len(lst)): if i ^ j > 0: if lst[i] ^ lst[j] == 0: print "Duplicate:", lst[i]

Comment: @Organis : Is it OK like this? It's not optimized, but it should work correctly now. Anyway I think the OP got the idea. At least, he should have.

Comment: Well, there are a lot of typos in the code, but the idea is nice (although a bit too complicated for my taste). Actually, it would be simpler if you dup += 1 each time x^y == 0 and then if dup ^ len(lst) > 0 then there are duplicates. Thus you utilize XOR twice and get the same result.

Comment: Gosh, what did I do now? If there are typos, please edit the thing. I am dead on my feet. You yourself didn't have to use xor to compare in your example. I==j would have worked just as fine. Yes I did complicate matters. Yes, unnecessarily. Sorry everyone. I will add more code with your suggestions in later today.

Comment: You've already fixed the missing print, now close the string and it will be fine : )

Comment: @Organis I'll take the liberty of fixing such small typos and let him sleep. :)

Comment: @Organis & MYGz  : Thank you people. Now the A should meet its votes.

Answer (score 1):

XOR takes the binary repersentation of a number and then compares it bit-by-bit with another and outputs a 1 if the two bits are different and a 0 otherwise. Example: 1 ^ 2 = 3 because in binary 1 is 01 and 2 is 10 so comparing bit-by-bit we get 11 or 3. XORing a number with itself always gives 0, so we can use this property to check if two numbers are the same. There are myriad better ways to check for duplicates in a list than using XOR, but if you want / need to do it this way, hopefully the above information gives you an idea of where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets use list items as bit indices:

```
def dupliXor(source):
    bigs = 0

    for x in source:
        b = 1<<x
        nexts = bigs ^ b

        # if xor removes the bit instead
        # of adding it then it is duplicate
        if nexts < bigs:
            print True
            return

        bigs = nexts

    print False

a = [1,2,3,4,5,19,22,25,17,6,73,72,71,77,899,887,44,124,1]

dupliXor(a) # True

a = [1,2,3,4,5,19,22,25,17,6,73,72,71,77,899,887,44,124]

dupliXor(a) # False
```

Comment: FWIW, `1<<x` is faster than `2**x`

Comment: Thanks, tested it and it's indeed 2 times faster.

Comment: @Organis, clever solution taking advantage of Python's unlimited integer value support. What are the memory usage implications of this, given that `b` and `bigs` will grow to be on the order of `2 ** max(source)` in magnitude?

Comment: @constantstranger You're not incorrect, however, the task was to use **XOR** (in spite of pure learning, I guess), not to make the solution sensible in any way.